# Kubernetes pods and shared memory and state

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am a Kubernetes noobie so my apologies if this is a basic question - I am trying to get a good understanding of this amazing technology.

Let's say I have some processing on a pod and I have some variables and arrays. Now I will have a heavy load, and a new pod will be dispensed/replicated - now I have 2 pods rather than 1 to handle my load. What will happen to the memory of the second pod? Is pod 2 replicated with the same memory contents? will memory be shared? If there is some communication across my microservices which requires memory to be consistent, in other words there is some variables dependency, then replicating a pod with fresh memory is catastrophic. For clarifcation, let us say there is a key, value map on one pod. A pod is replicated, then we have two key,value map (one on pod1 and another on pod2). But we want a key,value map containing all the data that is common between these two pods - a shared key,value map across replicated pods - NOT two isolated key,value maps.

Sure, I suppose one solution would be to have a shared, central, database for reference. But this is a massive overhead for situations where we just want to share an array of a few hundred elements! What is the Kubernetes approach to this issue?

Comment: This is an application-level design issue, not a Kubernetes thing.  What would you do if you had 2+ replicas of your service that you had deployed manually?

Comment: I would probably try to put some technique for communication across both replicas. But I don't know what that would manifest itself in. If this is not something to be handled at the Kubernetes level, then I would appreciate any comments on what would be good practice anyway.

Comment: Could you please share your experience on how you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your question about memory of the second pod, the second [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) will be assigned a new memory.

Addressing your question about the replicated memory content of the new pod, all the new pod will be replicated depending on the container spec.

Addressing your question about shared memory between pods, no the memory is not shared between the pods.If you want to share elements between pods, you need to make sure it is in container spec, such as [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) or [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

Addressing your question about key values, if you are looking for storage solutions, you could consider volumes [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/), [2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/). If you are just looking to pass some key-values to pods, you might consider using [configmaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

[1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

[2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/

Answer (score 1):

@Zeruno maybe i am thinking out loud here but what if you used the existing `etcd` cluster as a key-value store for your application

1. No overhead of maintaining it since its already there and manged by K8s itself 
   that too in a distributed cluster mode.
2. This might act as a single point of storage that will be accessible by all the pods in that cluster.

Comment: You can access ETCD indirectly via tags in YAML or ConfigMaps, but I've never seen Kube training or examples that expose the Kubernetes masters' ETCD cluster to applications.  Do you have any examples that demonstrate this, or any posts that claim this is a good practice?  My first instinct is to separate these concerns, the K/V store used by Kube should not be used directly by apps.  If your apps need ETCD then deploy a new instance into the cluster (via a Helm chart).  But then you'd need to consider alternatives like Redis.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you propose is appropriate sometimes, but I would only use it >1GB of shared data.  In your case "array of a few hundred elements" I'd use file watcher on a PVC (volume), but my cluster has fast SSD arrays for shared storage, I couldn't recommend it if you're running on traditional disks or traditional SAN.

That said, >1GB shared memory isn't implemented yet in Kubernetes, as of 2020-04-28.  See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28272 .

My reading of this thread is Kube limits shared memory to 64MB today.  If your dataset is that small you could read changes off of shared storage quickly enough (I'd guess 200ms-3sec).  If you need quicker I'd suggest using a caching service today: Redis with persistence disabled, or memcached, etc. and reconsider shared memory when issue 28272 is implemented.

Comment: P.S. Also on [issue #28272 thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28272) they ask for feedback on shared-memory scenarios and a few folks chimed in with scenarios similar to what I describe: >1GB of shared data or "shared database" being read/used by other processes.

Comment: Dear @Zeruno: I include this because you call yourself a "Kubernetes noobie".  Only pods on the **same node or server** will be able to read the shared memory.  And in any "cloud native" system like Kubernetes hosts/nodes can be patched and rebooted at the will of your operators (formerly known as IT).  That is the benefit of "shared central DB" or cache: the shared DB or cache could be configured for HA and tolerant of any single point of failure, but your shared memory is not, it's just some memory on a single node/server.